# How to delete buttons in the Markitup toolbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, markitup

I am using [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/). All I want is the paragraph button on the toolbar.

Anyone know how to delete the other buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file set.js in markitup/sets/default. Also you can specify the settings file to use with: $("#mark").markItUp(mySettings); where "mySettings" is the set.js file you want to use

Answer (score -1):

Find the file set.js and edit mysetting to include only what you need

Comment: mysetting is the default name inside set.js